# Laravel 8 Testing Method Illuminate\Http\JsonResponse::getSession does not exist

Tags: php, laravel, api, unit-testing, testing

How to get the updated session data from a JsonResponse during test, I want to make use of the updated session data to my next series of test.

I am using an api route, when i make use of `$response->dumpSession()` the session can be traced. But when I make use of `$response->getSession()->all` to pass this values to my next test request returns me a error.
[image]

when I tried to look for the property of the `$response` cannot find the property of session

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You can do `app('session.store')->all()`

Comment: @JuanEizmendi i make use the session helper to get the session, session()->all(), you can post the answer so I could accept it

Answer (score 0):

There is no `getSession` method on the `TestResponse` class. But instead you can use

```php
app('session.store')->all();
```

to achieve the same thing. This what the `dumpSession` uses under the hood also.